# Filtering an existing array to create a new, filtered array, using .map and .filter

Tags: arrays, swift

Consider the following `init()` function in one of my classes. The following code works great. The end result is that all courses are now in the courses map.

```
init() {
    courseRepository.$courses.map { courses in courses.map(CourseViewModel.init)}
    .assign(to: \.courseViewModels, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

I would next like to create a second map that contains only the courses that were created by the currently logged in user. The following is **not** working. Can you guys give me a hand?

```
init() {
    // 1
    courseRepository.$courses.map { courses in courses.map(CourseViewModel.init)}
    .assign(to: \.courseViewModels, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
    
    // add another repository just for the current user's courses
    justMyCourseRepository.$courses.map  =  courseRepository.$courses.map.filter { "\($0.createdBy)" == self.authState.loggedInUser!.uid }
    .assign(to: \.justMyCourseViewModels, on: self)
}
```

Comment: why are you assigning an array to map in 2nd example? Isn't it a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both `map` and `filter` as separate functions. You can't just assign some value to `justMyCourseRepository.$courses.map`.

What you can do is to `filter` the elements before applying `.map(CourseViewModel.init)` - this way your original mapping is untouched.

Even better solution (suggested by Leo Dabus) is to do everything in *one go* using `compactMap`:

```
justMyCourseRepository.$courses
    .map { courses in
        courses
            .compactMap {
                guard "\($0.createdBy)" == self.authState.loggedInUser!.uid else {
                    return nil
                }
                return CourseViewModel($0)
            }
    }
    .assign(to: \.justMyCourseViewModels, on: self)
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Thanks, @pawello2222 !!

Comment: You could avoid iterating the collection twice using a `compactMap` and a predicate to return nil or the courses mapped.